# Candidate template ignored: substitution failure

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, clang, clang++

I have a problem of substitution failure, and answers of some similar questions do not help me.

Here is the main part:

```
template<int dim, int loop>  
class Reference{
public:
   //...
   template<int r, int c> using matrix_t = int[r][c];
   Reference(const matrix_t<dim, loop> &mat){}
}; 

template<int dim, int loop>
class Partition{
    // ...
public:
    // ...
    template<int r, int c> using matrix = int[r][c];
    template<int r, int c> void readPattern(const matrix<r,c> &pattern)
    {
       // ...
    }
    // ...
};
```

And I call this template function like:

```
// ... 
const int DENOISE_UR[3][4] = {/*...*/};
Partition<1,2> partition;
partition.readPattern(DENOISE_UR);
// ...
```

When using clang++(linux) to compile, it resulted in the following compiling error:

```
 error: no matching function for call to 'readPattern'
   note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure[ with r = 3, c = 4 ]
         template<int r, int c> void readPattern(const matrix<r,c> &pattern)
```

Why?

What's weird is that the codes above did compile and work on Visual Studio 2013.

// ================================================================

I'm so sorry that it is my mistake in editing the question.  I have found that it does compile when taking this part out alone. But in my project, it only gives the above compiling error information.

So there must be some problems in my project.

// ================================================================

After some efforts, I have extracted out the problem revised as above by adding the main part of design of class `Reference<int dim, int loop>`

Can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: well it compiles here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/J3hEmTH5e3ARwIgc

Comment: What version of clang do you have?  [3.6.0 compiles this fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee6427402fb9e994).

Comment: @NathanOliver it is clang3.7.0, using `clang++ -std=c++11 xxx.cpp -ldl` to compile

Comment: Does this simple example fails too ? Or is it an error reported from the full code ?

Comment: It got compiled after, changing `readPattern` to `void readPattern` and `Partition partition;` to `Partition<1,2> partition;`

Comment: @Praveen I'm so sorry that it is my mistake in editing the question.  I have found that it does compile when taking this part out alone. But in my project, it only gives the above compiling information.

Comment: @Ninetainedo It is an error reported from the full code. When I add this statement `partition.readPattern(DENOISE_UR);` to my `main()` body, it reports the error... I just cannot figure out why...Could you figure out some hints?

Comment: Could you update the code above, please ? Or, even better, could you provide a real and full example on [this site](http://ideone.com) ? It will be easier for us to help you !